# Window.Current.CoreWindow KeyDown Event won't fire for "Tab" key Pressed in c#?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

what I have Tried is ?

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += keydown;
private void keydown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
   //Printing entered key
}
```

I'm developing UWP application.In my app Window.Current.CoreWindow
keydown event fired for all the keys in keyboard except "Tab" key.

I don't know why the event don't fire for that specific key?I want to do some actions while "Tab" key is pressed. Anyone know, how to fire the event when "Tab" key is pressed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By testing, sometimes pressing **Tab** key will not trigger `CoreWindow.KeyDown` event handler when there are some controls such as `Button` can get focus in a page. You could try to add a [UIElement.KeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown?view=winrt-19041) event or a [UIElement.PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.previewkeydown?view=winrt-19041) event to a page(such as `MainPage`) in xaml file.

**Update:**

When you use `CoreWindow.KeyDown` event and there are controls which could get focus in your page, pressing **Tab** key will let the focus step into a tab sequence instead of triggering the `CoreWindow.KeyDown` event. The `CoreWindow.KeyDown` event could be triggered when **Tab** key is pressed and the focus locates at the last control which could get focus.

If you want `CoreWindow.KeyDown` event to be triggered when **Tab** key is pressed, you could set `TabNavigation` as `Once` in your page. If you want save the **Tab** key’s feature that stepping into tab sequence, we still suggest you use `UIElement.KeyDown` event or `UIElement.PreviewKeyDown` event.
For example:
`Window.Current.Content.KeyDown += Content_KeyDown;`

**Update:**

`Window.Current.Content.KeyDown` event is a routed event. About routed event, you could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview). A routed event is an event that is potentially passed on (routed) from a child object to each of its successive parent objects in an object tree.

In your scenario, you could monitor the value of `e.OriginalSource` and you could view that when you step into the last control which could get focus by pressing **Tab** key the `KeyDown` event will be triggered twice. In the second trigger, the value of `e.OriginalSource` could be `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame`( may be different, subject to your observation in the second trigger). That’s because the routed `KeyDown` event need to bubble to its parent object at this time. You could add some code to identify the second trigger.

For example:

```
private void Content_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.ToString()!= "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame")
    {
        //Just be fired once here
    }
}
```

Note, you could try to use code `e.Handled = true;` to stop the routed behavior referring to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#the-handled-property). And, if you use `Page.KeyDown` event, there is no situation that KeyDown event be triggered twice.

Comment: I want to use CoreWindow KeyDown Event ,Is there anyother way?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you could view if the update could meet your requirements.

Comment: Window.Current.Content.KeyDown += Content_KeyDown ..If I use like this,sometimes the event has been fired twice for single keyDown.Do you know why this was happening?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you could view if the update could meet your requirements.